# Tag Property in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on an inventory system in Winforms and I need to bind all of the data from a custom object to a button control. Is there anyway that this can be achieved with the tag property, there are multiple ints and strings in the object I want to store. This block of code throws the error 'misc.weapon cannot be converted to object'

```
frm1.currentwep = ActiveControl.Tag;
```

frm1.currentwep is a custom object of type 'misc.weapon'. IMPORTANT (I think), the tag is from a dynamically created control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ActiveControl` is referencing the right control, and that you stored an instance of `misc.weapon` to the control's `Tag` property before doing this, just cast it back to the original type:

```
frm1.currentwep = (misc.weapon)ActiveControl.Tag;
```

Comment: Thanks Grant, not sure why I didn't think of that.